# Two Plugins not showing in CP after pushing to staging server

Tags: templating, plugins

Two different plugins not showing in the CP after code was pushed to staging server.

**My questions:**

**1) Why wouldn't the plugins show in CP if plugins are present in the craft_plugins table?**

**2) How to troubleshoot this issue?**  I'm not seeing any plugin errors in php-error.log or craft.log.

**What I know:**

-- Two plugins are NOT showing:

- truncHTML ( my own custom twigFilter )
- the "Import" plugin (
  boboldehampsink v 0.7.1- latest)
- Other plugins load fine.

-- Both "missing" plugins are present in the craft_plugins table.

-- Site seems to work file except for missing plugins, and related missing twig filter template error:

```
The filter "truncHTML" does not exist
```

-- My Development environment is php 5.4.24.
-- Staging is PHP 5.3.3 (where Plugins not loading)

- I confirmed that all Craft required PHP extensions are loading on the staging server

-- Craft dev mode enabled.

-- a similar truncate twig filter plugin loads fine.

```
2014/07/30 00:51:58 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "plugins" application component
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (594)
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (226)
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/index.php (196)
2014/07/30 00:51:58 [trace] [system.db.CDbCommand] Querying SQL: SELECT `id`, `class`, `version`, `settings`, `installDate`
FROM `craft_plugins`
WHERE enabled=1
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/services/PluginsService.php (101)
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (226)
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/index.php (196)
2014/07/30 00:51:58 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.query] begin:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT `id`, `class`, `version`, `settings`, `installDate`
FROM `craft_plugins`
WHERE enabled=1)
2014/07/30 00:51:58 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.query] end:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT `id`, `class`, `version`, `settings`, `installDate`
FROM `craft_plugins`
WHERE enabled=1)
2014/07/30 00:51:58 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "messages" application component
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (594)
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/Craft.php (402)
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/plugins/truncate/TruncatePlugin.php (13)
2014/07/30 00:51:58 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "i18n" application component
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (594)
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (826)
in /var/www/craft.dev/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (293)
```

-- I can include a stack trace detailing the twig "missing filter" error resulting from missing twig filter plugin, but I don't think this helps explain the missing plugin.

**Any Ideas?  Thanks!!**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check if the plugin folders in `craft/plugins` are named correctly. Most local environments aren't case-sensitive, but most servers are.

**Valid:**

`craft/plugins/trunchtml/`
`craft/plugins/import/`

**Invalid:**

`craft/plugins/truncHTML/`
`craft/plugins/Import/`

Comment: Simply changing the plugin foldernames to lowercase totally solved the issue. Thank you!