# Plugin not showing up in CP

Tags: plugins

I'm attempting to install the [Contact Form plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm). I believe that I've uploaded the correct folder to the correct location, but it's not showing up in the control panel. I'm relatively new to Craft, so this is the first plugin that I've installed.

This is my folder structure:

[image: Plugin Folder Structure]

I've seen a [couple](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/why-are-my-plugins-not-showing) [questions](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/two-plugins-not-showing-in-cp-after-pushing-to-staging-server/1537#1537) that indicate that the most common problem is improper capitalization on the plugin folder. However, as you can see, mine is all lower case.

I'm building this site on a Linux localhost and I've even gone so far as to `chmod 777 plugins -R` just to be sure it's not a permissions issue.

I've made sure to clear caches after every change, but no matter what I do I can not get the plugin to show up in the CP.

What else should I look at to diagnose and fix this?

Comment: +1 for doing solid research! Your screenshot confirms everything is in the right place. I would have guessed capitalization or permissions, but it seems you've ruled those out already.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit stumped. Nothing showing up in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`? If this is on a public box and you want to send some CP/FTP creds over to support@craftcms.com we can take a look and update here with any findings as well.

Comment: @LindseyD I'm a mod on [Bicycles SE](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com), so I understand [how to ask a good question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). :)

Comment: @BradBell It's not a public box. I'm headed out the door for work, but I'll check the logs when I get back home. What am I looking for?

Comment: Ahh, that explains it... Nicely done! :)

Comment: @jimirings I'd enable devMode, load the Craft plugin page in the control panel and check for any related `[warning]` or `[error]` entries in the logs.

Comment: @BradBell I didn't see anything, but I got it figured out (sort of). I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I deleted the whole contactform folder, downloaded it again, and added it back to the plugins folder. Just to be safe, I ran service httpd restart. After that, it showed up immediately.

I can't be sure, but I'm assuming that there was just something wrong with the originally downloaded files.

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Ahh... weird.  Thanks for the follow up and glad you got it sorted!