# Plugin won't enable

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I have created my own plugin. It works on my Mac but when I try to enabled it in my Debian server it shows as Disabled with a red dot. What's the best way to debug this?

I have not found anything particularly illuminating in the logs yet.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out I had a capitalization typo in my plugin php file name.

`myPlugin.php`

`class MyPlugin ...`

Renaming the file to `MyPlugin.php` solved it. (capitial M)

So it would seem that the file and class name need to match exactly.

Comment: Indeed they do. :) [Here are the full specs on where to use which casing...](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the name of your plugin directory is all lowercase:

```
/craft/plugins/myplugin
```

On some systems, the capitalization doesn't matter, but on other systems it makes a difference. ([related](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1537/45))

Comment: Turns out it was the class name. I've posted that below.

Answer (score 1):

for me was the file

```
vendor/craftcms/plugins.php
```

it was referencing a wrong class name due to refactor error (plugin development)