# Plugin won't enable on remote dev enviornment

Tags: plugin-development

I've got exactly the same issue reported here:
[Plugin won't enable](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/plugin-wont-enable)

I've created a really simple plugin that works fine on my local environment but won't enable on my remote dev server. I've followed the advice in that Question and checked all the file and class names but with no success.

There doesn't seem to be any indication of problems in the logs either. I'm stumped. =(

Here's the code as requested:
FirstImagePlugin.php - http://pastebin.com/ehVHF9vk
FirstImageTwigExtension.php - http://pastebin.com/D5C8QnjK

The directory structure is simply just:
/plugins/firstimage/twigextensions

Comment: usually it's really related to filename capitalization so make sure to double check that. Is it possible to show us the plugincode (via gist or similar), or is it private?

Comment: Added it to the original question

Comment: When you say "won't enable" you mean it's not showing up under Settings->Plugins?  Or it is, you click enable and some other error happens?

Comment: It's showing, I click **Enable**, the page refreshes with no errors and the plugin is still shown as disabled

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue, then check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for either `[error]` or `[warning]` entries and see if there is anything related?