# Cannot enable Craft plugin in control panel

Tags: plugins, control-panel

I'm attempting to enable a plugin from within the Craft control panel but I am unable to do so. It shows Disabled and when I click "Enable" it shows "Plugin Enabled" at the top but still shows disabled below and will not enable.

I'm not getting any errors reported and it seems to work on other environments just will not work now?

Comment: Related: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/plugin-wont-enable

Answer (score 5):

My guess is it's a case sensitivity issue with the main plugin class/file name (some operating systems have case sensitive filesystems and some don't).

You can review the requirements for how things should be named here: https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up

Or better yet, use a site like https://pluginfactory.io/ to generate the boilerplate plugin code for you and compare it to what you have.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance all of the file names and database were correct.

We had not run our composer dump-autoload script in several months since we updated the name which caused this issue.